# How to show Loading Screen in Browser with Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch-2

**Disclaimer: I know how to create a startup screen on mobile devices.**

Is it possible to show a loading screen for a Sencha Touch 2 application if accessed via the browser?

*If yes, please give a concise, working example.* Proof-of-concept app, Gist, source, you know.

I am talking about something like the Sencha Docs loading screen:

[image: Sencha Docs loading screen]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a loading indicator to your index.html. Just make sure it loads fast so the user gets an instant feedback that something is going on.

```
<div id="appLoadingIndicator"></div>
```

Once the app launches call

```
// Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
```

This is done for you in case you [use Sencha Cmd to generate new applications](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/command_app).

Also have a look at these [smooth CSS3 indicators](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourContainer.setMasked({
    xtype: 'loadmask',
    message: 'Loading...'
});
```

then add a timer

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // code to be executed when loading
    // Unmask the container
    form.setMasked(false);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This masks a component, I want to show a loading screen on application startup.